# How to compute $\log\binom {n_H + n_T}{n_H}$?

Tags: logarithms, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to conduct a justification of the [MLE on Bernoulli distribution](https://youtu.be/He_D2KWXyQU?t=3795).

\begin{align}
P(D\mid \theta) &= \binom {n_H + n_T}{n_H} \theta^{n_H} (1 - \theta)^{n_T}, 
\end{align}

plug in the definition and compute the log-likelihood:

\begin{align}
 \hat{\theta}_{MLE} &= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\theta} \,P(D; \theta) \\
  &= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\theta} \binom {n_H + n_T}{n_H} \theta^{n_H} (1 - \theta)^{n_T} \\
&= \operatorname*{argmax}_{\theta} \,\log\binom {n_H + n_T}{n_H} + n_H \cdot \log(\theta) + n_T \cdot \log(1 - \theta) 
\end{align}

How do I compute $\log\binom {n_H + n_T}{n_H}$?

Comment: I don't think you need to care about what $\log \binom{n_H+n_T}{n_H}$ since to find argmax, you need to differentiate with respect to $\theta$, and $\log \binom{n_H+n_T}{n_H}$ vanishes after differentiation.

Comment: In other words, $\log\binom{n_H+n_T}{n_H}$ is just a constant wrt. $\theta$, so it does not influence the maximum point. (It just moves the graph vertically).

Comment: @Jerry  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to care about what $\log \binom{n_H+n_T}{n_H}$ is since to find argmax, you need to differentiate with respect to , and $\log \binom{n_H+n_T}{n_H}$ vanishes after differentiation.